# Show fcm notification if meet a condition with swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

I am using firebase push notification, where my app is subscribed to a topic, all is good. But I want to know if it is possible to show the notification if pass a notification. this is my scene:

```
local_user_id = 10

var payload = {
  notification: {
    title: "hi",
    body: "this is a notification",
    sound: "default"
  },
  data: {
    user_id: "1",
    message: "you should pay $3020.25"
  }
};
```

1) control if user is_login (true/false)
2)get the message data of notification and check:

```
if (payload.data.user_id = local_user_id && is_login){
     show_notification()
  }
```

3) show notification

Actually I only have the notification and no more, I am new with firebase, this is my code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
                (granted, error) in
            }
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            FirebaseApp.configure()
            return true
    }

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
            let dict = userInfo["aps"] as! NSDictionary
            let message = dict["alert"]
            print("response")
            print(message)
        }
```

I don't know how to do that what I want, is it posible?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can not control show hide notification in your application. You can put some logic on the backend side, whether this notification should be displayed or not. Nevertheless, I have workaround below possible way.

- Use a **silent push.** Then trigger local notifications. Note: Silent
  push isn't always reliable.
- So just include **content-available: 1** in your payload as shown
  below to get a silent notification.it will act as silent notification.
- Also in **Info.plist** should have **UIBackgroundModes** set to
  **remote-notification**

but it'll be limited to Running and background mode only. you won't be able to receive or handle it if **content-available** is set to 0 while your app is offline

Comment: ok I understand is not posible. but Where can I handle the data in receivemessage or in UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to just present the notification to the user while the app is running in the foreground, you would need to have your AppDelegate conform to the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`. This is because when the application is running, the notifications will be presented to the `UNUserNotificationCenter` shared object.

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void {

        let content = notification.request.content
        if content.data["user_id"] == local_user_id && is_login {
            completionHandler(.alert)
        } else {
            completionHandler([])
        }
    }
}
```

You would want to make sure that the completionHandler is executed at some point in this block, because this is the handler that does the presentation of the notification.  If you want a silent notification, you can use `completionHandler([])` to silence the alert.  Other possible options for the completionHandler are available [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationpresentationoptions).

Comment: how about with the condition? how can I get first the message and after show the notification?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're asking there.  The notification is always being sent to the user but you only want to show it to them if they're logged in? If that's the case, you can check for the condition in the `userNotificationCenter:willPresent` method, see the edit above.

Comment: that works when app is in active and background and inactive?

becasuse when app is closed the notification appears

Comment: When the app is inactive and in the background, the notification will go through the `func application:didReceiveRemoteNotification` method instead of the `userNotificationCenter:willPresent` method.

Comment: so, should I copy the condition into that method?

Comment: I don't think that will work. I believe at the point in which `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification` is called, the notification is already on the device.  The conditional logic should really be handled at the point of sending the notification.  If you are intending notifications to only be sent to particular users, you should send those notifications directly to those users instead of to everyone via a topic.